# Socket.IO Handshake Authorization

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I have the following in my NodeJS server to ensure that `foo=bar` in the handshake of the connection request:

```
io.use(function(socket, next){
    console.log("Query: ", socket.handshake.query);
    // return the result of next() to accept the connection.
    if (socket.handshake.query.foo == "bar") {
        console.log("Got auth params.");
        socket.emit('chat message','Valid credentials.');
        return next();
    }
    // call next() with an Error if you need to reject the connection.
    console.log("Didn't get auth params.");
    socket.emit('chat message','Invalid credentials.');
    next(new Error('Authentication error'));
});
```

When `foo=bar` in the handshake data the `chat message` indicating 'Valid credentials.' is successfully emitted to the client.  However, when `foo!=bar` socket.emit does not emit the 'Invalid credentials.' chat message.

Is it possible send a message to the client that requested the connection in the event that `foo!=bar`?

I'm assuming it's likely that the only way to emit a message to the client in response to their connection request is by accepting the connection with `return next()`, sending a message in the `connection` event indicating the invalid credentials, then terminating the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to catch the error message emitted via `next(new Error('Authentication error'))` simply create a handler for the `error` event on the client side as such:

```
socket.on('error', function(err){
  console.log('Connection Failed: ' + err);
});
```